# How will I know if two files are identical?

Tags: windows-xp

I am currently developing an application and compile it to create a `.exe` file. Then our operations team copy the compiled application in our test client computer.

Now, an error occur when testing the application in the client and the possible cause would be because the complied application in the client is not the latest one.

**How can I check that the `.exe` file in the client and in my development environment are identical?**

The *file size* was the same even when a different compile was made so I can't verify it by comparing the file size. I cant also compare it using the *created date* because obviously it was only the date when the file is created, in our client's case, the date when the file is copied. We do not implement version yet and I can't use a file comparing application since the client's PC is at different location.

Both mine and the client's OS is in Windows XP.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `fc` or `comp` for comparing files. Both will tell you whether or not they are identical.

Comment: How can I use it if the files that I compare is at different locations, although at the same private network?

Comment: Just specify the location along with the file name? E.g. `fc foo.exe \\someserver\share\foo.exe`?

Comment: Thanks. It seems like they are identical. Now back to debugging.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a file hash utility like [**md5**](http://www.fourmilab.ch/md5/) (command line) or [**HashTab**](http://www.implbits.com/hashtab.aspx) (GUI).