# Recursively compare file identities in Windows environment using only standard Windows commandline tools

Tags: windows, command-line, diff, recursion

I want to ensure that deep directories of files are identical after copying.

I've read this answer: https://superuser.com/a/414216/214579

However, neither fc or comp offer recursion.  How would one implement recursive testing in a pure windows environment.

This answer strongly indicates that robocopy is probably very very useful: https://superuser.com/a/748518/214579

Comment: I second the notion about robocopy. Take a closer look at it, it can do the trick. ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can and should use [Robocopy](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/1073.robocopy-and-a-few-examples.aspx) for that.

```
robocopy c:\folder1 c:\folder2 \mir
```

Will make sure that both folders are identical including subfolders. It will also remove files that have been deleted.

There are lots of other options too including being able to watch folders for changes, retry if files are locked and so on.